# What are projective sets in Set Theory?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

I try to write a simply definition of "projective set" in Set Theory context.
I read [here](https://sci-hub.do/10.1016/s0049-237x%2808%2971121-2)

1. The operation for generating sets from the open sets is called *projection*. The projection of $A$ is then a subset of $\mathcal N^n$
2. The class of projective sets is the closure of the open sets under the operations of projection and complementation.
   The projective sets form a pointclass and are closed (within each $\mathcal N^n$) under unions and intersections (but not countable unions and intersections)

But I don't understand well because projective sets come from Borel sets, Polish spaces context (approach of Moschovakis). Can you help me to clarify?

Comment: Please don't link to SciHub. Just give an actual bibliographic citation.

Comment: Where did you get "but not countable unions and intersections"? Also, are you aware that what you wrote as $N$ (usually $\mathcal N$) is not the set of natural numbers but the Baire space?

Comment: @AndreasBlass I read [here](https://imgur.com/M8AqTje.png) --> text is "*Descriptive Set Theory: projective sets*" by Donald A. Martin

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, you are right, because before he write "*We prefer, however, to deal with a single concrete Polish space. We do not use the real line, because that space is slightly awkward to use. Instead we use Baire space $\omega$, which we denote by $\mathcal N$.
1.1. DEFINITION. $\omega$ is the set of all natural numbers. $\mathcal N$ is the collection of all functions $\alpha : \omega \rightarrow \omega$. We give $\omega$ the discrete topology and, thinking of $\mathcal N$ as the product of infinitely many copies of $\omega$, we give $\mathcal N$ the product topology*"

Comment: I don't understand well because we need to start from Baire space or Polish space to develop the concept of Projective set.

Comment: Of possible use: Glen Alan Schlee, [**On the Development of Descriptive Set Theory**](https://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc500836/), Master of Arts thesis (under Richard Daniel Mauldin), University of North Texas (Denton, Texas), August 1988, iii + 66 pages. FYI, Schlee was a colleague of mine 1993-96, and in summer 1999 I spent a couple of weeks LaTeX'ing his MA thesis (because all he had was a paper copy, of which I had a photocopy of), and then a couple of years ago I discovered that a digital copy is now freely available . . . (however my LaTeX copy has a few extra notes by me)

Comment: As Martin explains shortly before the passage you quoted, he chooses to work with $\mathcal N$ but the definitions and theorems (though not exactly the same proofs) work for other perfect Polish spaces. The use of $\mathcal N$ simplifies proofs because $\mathcal N^2\cong\mathcal N$, so one can deal with projections without worrying about dimensions.

Comment: Also, although each level (like $\mathbf\Sigma^1_n$ or $\mathbf\Pi^1_n$) of the projective hierarchy is closed under countable unions, the whole hierarchy is not. If you take one set from each level of the hierarchy, the union might fail to be projective.

Comment: Suppose that X is a topological space. If every comeager set in X is dense,
we say that X is a Baire space.  A Polish space is a separable completely metrizable topological space; that is, a space homeomorphic to a complete metric space that has a countable dense subset. Polish spaces are also a convenient setting for more advanced measure theory, in particular in probability theory. A projective set that can be obtained from Borel sets by repeated application of the operations of projection and taking complements. Projective sets are classified in classes forming the projective hierarchy.

Comment: the Baire sets form a σ-algebra of a topological space. What I don't understand is the link between projective sets and probability theory